# Wrapping a react-bootstrap component Typescript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a wrapper component around Bootstrap's `Alert` component.

The `Alert` component has `Link` and `Heading` properties on it so you can do `<Alert.Link>`- see https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Alert.js#L119.

```
import React from 'react';
import BootstrapAlert, { AlertProps } from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

const Alert = (props: AlertProps) => {
  return <BootstrapAlert bsPrefix="my-app-alert" {...props} />;
};

export default Alert;
```

When I render:

```
<Alert variant='primary'>
  Hello 
  <Alert.Link href="#">world</Alert.Link>
</Alert>
```

I get the Typescript error:

```
Property 'Link' does not exist on type '(props: AlertProps) => Element'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the `Alert.Link` and `Alert.Heading` components from bootstrap's alert namespace onto your custom `Alert` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import BootstrapAlert, { AlertProps } from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

const Alert = (props: AlertProps) => {
  return <BootstrapAlert bsPrefix="my-app-alert" {...props} />;
};

// Copy the Heading and Link components from Bootstrap as well
// You might need to declare the Heading and Link properties on your Alert type too
Alert.Heading = BootstrapAlert.Heading;
Alert.Link = BootstrapAlert.Link;

export default Alert;
```

---

If you look at the source for **react-bootstrap/src/Alert.js** you can see how they're defining their Alert namespace:

```
// Define the Alert component
const Alert = React.forwardRef((uncontrolledProps, ref) => {
    //...implementation
});

// Then at the bottom of the file they add the `Alert.Link` and
// `Alert.Heading` properties to the component:

Alert.Link = createWithBsPrefix('alert-link', {
  Component: SafeAnchor,
});

Alert.Heading = createWithBsPrefix('alert-heading', {
  Component: DivStyledAsH4,
});

export default Alert;
```

This is what gives you the react-bootstrap API:

```
// Standard react-bootstrap usage
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

<Alert>
    <Alert.Heading>My alert heading</Alert.Heading>
    <Alert.Link>My link content</Alert.Link>
</Alert>
```